# Why doesn't JavaScript textContent assign the proper text in this code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, frontend

I was doing an exercise I found on MDN website and I couldn't finish this one. The point is to use JSON, extract data from it and then display it on the page. The code works, it generates the strings as it should, I checked the console and everything is as it is supposed to be. It just won't assign the generated strings to the textContent properties of created paragraphs. When I do the same assignment in the console it works perfectly.

"""

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>

        </section>
        <script>
            const section = document.querySelector('section');


            let requestURL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdn/learning-area/master/javascript/oojs/tasks/json/sample.json";
            let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", requestURL);
            request.responseType = "json";
            request.send();


            let kittenInfo;
            let motherInfo = "The mothers are";


            request.onload = function() {
                let catString = request.response;
                extractInfo(catString);
            }

            function extractInfo(info){
                let end = ", ";;
                let total = 0;
                let male = 0;
                let names = "";

                for (let i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                    if (i === info.length - 2) {
                        end = " and";
                    }else if (i === info.length - 1){
                        end = ".";
                    }
                    motherInfo += " " + info[i].color + " " + info[i].breed + " " + info[i].name + end;

                    for (let j = 0; j < info[i].kittens.length; j++) {
                        end = ",";
                        if (i === info.length - 1) {
                            if (j === info[i].kittens.length - 2){
                                end = " and";
                            }else if (j === info[i].kittens.length - 1){
                                end = ".";
                            }
                        }

                        if (info[i].kittens[j].gender === "m"){
                            male += 1;
                        }

                        names += " " + info[i].kittens[j].name + end;
                        total += 1;
                    }
                }
                kittenInfo = `There are ${total} kittens, ${male} of them are male and ${total - male} of them are female. ` + 
                      `Their names are ${names}`;
            } 


            let para1 = document.createElement("p");
            let para2 = document.createElement("p");

            para1.textContent = motherInfo;
            para2.textContent = kittenInfo;

            section.appendChild(para1);
            section.appendChild(para2);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the text content before you have the response from the HTTP request.

You'll need to move the `para1.textContent = ...`, etc., to inside your `extractInfo()` function.